# typeof variablename == function not working

Tags: javascript, function, variables, typeof

I have an array with function names, I would like the code below to iterate through the array with function names and check if the function name exists.

If func_3 does not exist, it should check if func_4 exists and not stop the loop till it checks if all functions in the array exist

I have spent a lot of time on this but cant figure it out where am i going wrong, please help

**Demo Code**

```
          function func_1(){
              alert("FUNCTION EXISTS");
            }
            function func_2(){
              alert("FUNCTION EXISTS");
            }
            var functions = ["func_1", "func_2", "func_3", "func_4"];
            for(var i=0;i < functions.length; i++){
                var func_name = functions[i];
                if(typeof func_name=='function') {
                    alert("HELLO WORLD");
                }   
                alert("ITERATING WELL");
            }
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce your issue? This doesn't sound right...

Comment: This should work in both cases. Are you receiving any specific errors in console?

Comment: @Spencer T. i have put a demo code, please have a look

Comment: @elclanrs i have put a demo code, can you please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your function is as follows :

```
function req(){
alert('hello world');
}
```

then

```
console.log(typeof req) //output "function"

var a=req

console.log(typeof a) //output "function"
```

because both 'req' and 'a' are function type.

==========================================================

## updated

if you still want to invoke javascript function using updated code, use following :

```
function func_1(){
alert("FUNCTION EXISTS");
}
function func_2(){
alert("FUNCTION EXISTS");
}
var functions = ["func_1", "func_2", "func_3", "func_4"];
for(var i=0;i < functions.length; i++){
var func_name = new Function(functions[i]);
if(func_name && typeof func_name=='function') {
alert("HELLO WORLD");
}   
alert("ITERATING WELL");
}
```

it seems 'var foo = new Function(functions[i])' is what you are looking for

Comment: @ark3typ3 oh now i understand, what is happening is when the function 'req' does not exists, it is breaking the loop. How can i keep the loop to iterate even if function does not exist

Comment: @Manu pls add code. We can't understand which loop are you talking about

Comment: you can check if function is defined using if(reg and typeof req=='function')

Comment: @Anupam Singh i have put a demo code, please have a look

Comment: error is in line=>  var functions = [func_1, func_2, func_3, func_4]; 1. remove quotes from array element, 2. since  func_3 and func_4 are not defined you can'not add those in array.

Comment: @Anupam Singh thank you for trying to help, the new function is not exactly what i am looking, adding a new function is creating a new function regardless if the function exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have such problems just try to console.log(variable_name) the variables and check the results by pressing F12 on your page with the script. In your case it's 
console.log(typeof req);
console.log(typeof a);